# SpringBatch - Execute next step even on failure of first step

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am looking for

- Execute steps sequentially
- Irrespective of Failure or Success status of earlier step next step should be executed

Below is the code snippet which helps to achieve point 1), but job stops on *step 1* failure there by *step 2* not getting chance to run.

```
RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener()).flow(step1).next(step2).end().build();
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `flow(step1).on("*").to(step2).end().build();`?

Comment: Hey friend, your suggestion is fine and also seems to be working for my scenario. Thank you.

Comment: Sad, but don't see this is working for exception like org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException

Comment: The error OptimisticLockingFailureException was coming because of common   references shared between threads. After fixing code this error went away ( yet no occurrence caught ).